# Авто добавлять материал в значение <select> <option>пост

Tags: select

цель такая, создал форму, в пункте select выпадающий список  указываю письменно выбор нужного пункта, можно ли указать скрипт или код название нового добавленного материала?

суть: есть форма, в ней я создал выползающий список, а в нём названия материалов. Но, как сделать чтоб при добавлении материала название TITLE добавлялось автоматически?

[image: так сейчас]

[image: нужно так]

Comment: Формулировка вопроса божественна, но лучше быть ближе к народу и разъяснить подробнее.

Comment: сама форма. <select class="mfield" name="f3"><option>Выбор фестиваля *</option> 
<option>Скоро </option>
</select> 
вместо "Скоро" требуется поставить скрит который будет добавлять название при добавлении нового материала ( публикации )